# Pseudo-random ordering in django queryset

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have a QuerySet that returns 10 objects, 3 of which will be displayed in the following positions:

```
[ display 1 position ]      [ display 2 position ]     [ display 3 position ]
```

The model representing it is as follows:

```
class FeaturedContent(models.Model):
    image = models.URLField()
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

where position can be either 1, 2, 3, or unspecified (Null).

I want to be able to order the QuerySet randomly EXCEPT FOR the objects with a specified position. However, I can't order it by doing:

```
featured_content = FeaturedContent.objects.order_by('-position', '?')
```

Because if I had one item that had `position = 2`, and all the other items were `Null`, then the item would appear in position 1 instead of position 2.

How would I do this ordering?

Thinking about this, perhaps it would be best to have the data as a dict instead of a list, something like:

```
`{'1': item or null, '2': item or null, '3': item or null, '?': [list of other items]}`
```

Comment: You should really avoid random ordering within your database (as also the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) points out) as it tends to be really slow!

Comment: Then what's a better way to do what I need to do above?

Answer (score 0):

I would post process it, doing a merge sort between the ordered and unordered records.

**EDIT:**

The beginnings of a generator for this:

```
def posgen(posseq, arbseq, posattr='position', startpos=1):
  posel = next(posseq)
  for cur in itertools.count(startpos):
    if getattr(posel, posattr) == cur:
      yield posel
      posel = next(posseq)
    else:
      yield next(arbseq)
```

Note that there are lots of error conditions possible in this code (hint: `StopIteration`).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to iterate over the queryset you can have two querysets, order them and chain them.

```
import itertools

qs1 = FeaturedContent.objects.filter(position__isnull=False).order_by('-position')
qs2 = FeaturedContent.objects.filter(position__isnull=True).order_by('?')
featured_content = itertools.chain(qs1, qs2)
for item in featured_content:
    #do something with qs item
    print item
```

Upadate:

Since you are asking to make sure position determines the order and the "blank" spaces are replaced randomly by elements with null positions. If the featured list you want to obtain is not too large, 20 in this case

```
featured = []
rands = []
for i in xrange(1, 20):
    try:
        x = FeaturedContent.objects.get(position=i) # assuming position is unique
    except FeaturedContentDoesNotExist:
        if not rands:
            rands = list(FeaturedContent.objects.filter(position__isnull=True).order_by('?')[:20]
        x = rands[0]
        rands = rands[1:]
    featured.append(x)
```

Comment: +1 for being faster =), however -1 for it does not fulfill the requirement that item w/ position 2 should be at position 2 when other items having null position

Comment: Correct, this doesn't do anything in terms of ordering as specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a db backend that does random ordering efficiently you could do it like this:

```
# This will hold the result
featured_dict = {}

featured_pos = FeaturedContent.objects.filter(position__isnull=False).order_by('-position')
featured_rand = FeaturedContent.objects.filter(position__isnull=True).order_by('?')

pos_index = 0    
rand_index = 0

for pos in range(1, 4):
    content = None

    if pos_index < len(featured_pos) and featured_pos[pos_index].position == pos:
        content = featured_pos[pos_index]
        pos_index += 1

    elif rand_index < len(featured_rand):
        content = featured_rand[rand_index]
        rand_index += 1

    featured_dict[str(pos)] = content

# I'm not sure if you have to check for a valid index first before slicing
featured_dict['?'] = featured_rand[rand_index:]
```